# violin plot: description for a paper

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I find violinplots quite pretty, but the way it is calculated is difficult to grasp for non-statisticians, the documentation is quite rudimentary.
I am using the default values of the geom_violin function of ggplot2 in R. Does anybody knows **what I could write in the material and method** part of the paper, or get me a nice reference for it.

By the way, is the use of these plots clever, even if the distribution of the data is unknonwn?
(example of figure can be seen here: https://github.com/jcolomb/learningdata/blob/master/flightdata/analysis_R/firsttest_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-2-1.pdf)

Comment: Wikipedia gives a reference, which is available online (maybe not legal): https://quantixed.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/hintze_1998.pdf

Comment: In my area of research you don't see them often, but I have used violin plots in a publication and didn't need to write anything about them in Materials & Methods. It was sufficient to mention that they depict distributions.

Comment: The ggplot2 violin plot uses the `density` function to calculate a 1D kernel density estimate. The [help page](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/density) for `density` includes several references.

Answer (score 4):

For [one of our papers](http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/282/1812/20151132), that used violin plots with boxplots overlaid, we used the following description in the figure legend:

> Parameters of inspection behaviour for the different treatments presented as boxplots, indicating the median and quartiles with whiskers reaching up to 1.5 times the interquartile range. **The violin plot outlines illustrate kernel probability density, i.e. the width of the shaded area represents the proportion of the data located there.**

This was agreed on after an editor told us the previous description was too technical, as he himself didn't know what violin plots were.

Answer (score 0):

Hadley documents the source of violinplots here in de code:
https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-violin.r#L20-L21

Which you would have found if you use `?geom_violin` and read the documentation.
He references: Hintze, J. L., Nelson, R. D. (1998) Violin Plots: A Box Plot-Density Trace Synergism. The American Statistician 52, 181-184

And for completeness here is the DOI:
http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2685478